# Sonarqube API single class test coverage

Tags: api, sonarqube, test-coverage

I am trying to retrieve the unit test code coverage for individual classes through the SonarQube API (Sonar version 4.1.2). Everything is working fine, and I can see the metrics okay when I go directly to the sonar dashboard and go to the coverage tab for a class:

```
    93.9%   by unit tests Line coverage: 97.9% (285/291) Branch coverage: 85.0% (113/133)
```

Can anyone tell me the correct call to retrieve this same/similar information through the sonar API interface please? I've already had a look at the documentation at http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+definitions and can get test coverage metrics back at project level but I can't see how to construct a query for individual classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you are after

[hostname]/api/resources?resource=[com.test]:[module-name]:[fully qualified class]&metrics=coverage,branch_coverage

I have added an example below.

http://sonar-server/api/resources?resource=com.test:module:com.test.service.impl.CheckServiceImpl&metrics=coverage,branch_coverage

I looked at the page you shared and used this also :

http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743280

Answer (score 0):

`api/measures/component_tree` is your friend

```
result = session.get(        
    SONAR_BASE + "api/measures/component_tree",        
    params={"baseComponentId": COMPONENT, "metricKeys": "coverage"   )
)
```

gets you coverage down to the file level. You should be able to only get the files with the `"leaves"` strategy.