# Sonar Web Service - Code Coverage Metrics

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to extract sonar code coverage metrics via the [Sonar Web Service](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743280) documentation.

The [Sonarqube API single class test coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959322/sonarqube-api-single-class-test-coverage) recommends that i should use this pattern for my target class name

```
https://[hostname]/api/resources?resource=com.a.b.c.d.om:[module-name]:com.a.b.c.d.e.mobile.XYZActionHandler&metrics=coverage,branch_coverage
```

but i've found that only using the java source path in the resource name works

```
https://[hostname]/api/resources?resource=com.a.b.c.d.om:[module-name]:src/main/java/com/a/b/c/d/e/actions/mobile/XYZActionHandler.java&metrics=coverage,branch_coverage
```

Can someone explain why the first URL fails but the second one works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the version of SonarQube that you use.

In recent versions (at least since the last LTS, probably as far as 4.2), a Java component's key is indeed its path, whereas in older versions it was its fully qualified name (package.Class).

Comment: Use v4.2. Is there a way to query the key by java classname?

Comment: I don't think so, but you should be able to build the new key using the Java class name, depending on the structure of your project. For instance, in a standard Maven project, a Java file key will always be ``project.key:module.key:src/main/java/some/package/MyClass.java``.

Comment: true - but it means i've to pull information from the pom.xml to determine the project and module keys. thanks