# Import code coverage calculated from sonarqube dashboard on TFS dashboard

Tags: c#, tfs, sonarqube, azure-devops

I have visual studio and code in c# .net, and using TFS for code check in. Now I am using sonarqube to find out code coverage and bugs etc parameters for my code. So I am able to see them on my sonarqube dashboard, now I want to import that statistics on my TFS dashboard from sonarqube dashboard. How can I do that. Can anyone guide me please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t the built-in widget to import sonarqube code coverage result in TFS dashboard. You can try to [build a custom extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/overview) with [SonarQube Web Service API](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE43/Web+Service+API) to get the related report and show in that extension.

A related thread about get code coverage through Sonaqube API: [Sonarqube API single class test coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959322/sonarqube-api-single-class-test-coverage)